# Layout. Trailing footer

Tags: stack, footer

Need to attach a footer to the bottom of the browser. And when you are scrolling the page, footer does't move.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px; //or other fixed
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This style should wrap all your footer content. This will make it stick on the bottom of the page, no matter how much you scroll down.

To make the same thing up or on a side, you also should use absolute.

Comment: Added a better comment for you. All your footer content should be inside #footer. Also, left:0 and right:0 are not necessary if using a div, but it is if using something else.